# How to run Command Prompt of Host Machine from Virtual Box?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I would like to execute a bat file on the host machine because it is the only place that contains the program. My VM does not contain the required program to run the bat file. How can I call the command prompt from the guest machine so that I can run the bat file?

Comment: Are both your host and guest Windows?

Comment: Yes, they are both using windows

Answer (score 1):

Virtual machines aren't really designed to do that.  However you can use something like PSExec to remotely connect to the host from the VM if they're sharing the same network (default), or there's a path through the gateways to connect to it.  You want to run a batch file, so I'm assuming you're using some version of Windows, so something like this should work:

`psexec \\<Computername/IP Address> -d -l -u <Username> <Program to run> <Arguments>`

The `-d` will not be interactive, so it's fire and forget.  If you omit that argument, you'll be able to work with the program on the command line, no GUI though.  If you replace `-d` with `-i`, then it should pop-up on the host, but I'm not sure if that's what you want or not.